# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

Tags: java

I am getting the error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist.util.proxy.Proxy** in my app. I am using javassist version 3.12.1.GA in my app, but it does not contain this class. Does anyone know where I can download a version of the javassist JAR that has the javassist.util.proxy.Proxy class?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @Flexo, I don't think OP is asking for opinion, but solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**javassist.util.proxy.Proxy** is available in the version **3.16.1-GA** of javassist,

which can be downloaded from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA/javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar).

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist to get all relevant versions

Answer (score 0):

u can find depency jar in [Apache Central Maven Repository](http://search.maven.org) ,Go into the site and type `javaassist` in search area then u`ll see the jar list.

Comment: you mean https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist

Comment: It looks like the same,  mvnrepository.com is one of a mirror site from Central Maven Repository, u could also find out the depency from repository like Jboss or Spring